# I want to make sure my way of identifying ID is secure

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to fetch user info even if they are not logged in just to display image and name on login page if they visit my website with there own profile links.

Before and till now i am using this method

```
//file to connect db 
require_once 'incdb/db.inc.con.php';

//check to see if they're logged in else head them to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// checking user
$userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $_GET['userID']);
$Check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$userID'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Check)) {
    $pid = $row['id'];
    $pfname = $row['firstname'];
    $plname = $row['lastname'];
}
```

So now i am trying to do little changes and making name visible on login page if they visit by there own links like `http://www.example.com/member.php?userID=1` and i will be adding name and image `meta properties` so my code will look like

```
//file to connect db 
require_once 'incdb/db.inc.con.php';

// checking user
$userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $_GET['userID']);
$Check = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$userID'");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Check)) {
    $pid = $row['id'];
    $pfname = $row['firstname'];
    $plname = $row['lastname'];
}

//check to see if they're logged in else head them to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

this is what i was talking about meta

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com"/> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/user/image.jpg"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="User Name"/>
```

Comment: Better way than using `*_real_escape_string`, only if your userID is always an integer, is to cast it as integer : `$userID = isset($_GET['userID']) ? (int) $_GET['userID'] : 0;`. Then check if userID is not 0, then query. By the way you could also use a [prepared query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to do it

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me i am sure you used https://github.com/philip/MySQLConverterTool which helps to make bit more secure code but its better if you use your own MySQLi  code